# Can you cancel an async function with lodash debounce?

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
const asyncMethod = async () => {
    const data = await fetchData()
    return data.map(parseResponse)
})

const a = _.debounce(asyncMethod, 0, { leading: true })
```

Could you call `a.cancel()` and also have the async method stop?

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce):

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after
>   wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced
>   function was invoked. The debounced function **comes with a cancel**
>   **method to cancel delayed func invocations** and a flush method to
>   immediately invoke them. Provide options to indicate whether func
>   should be invoked on the leading and/or trailing edge of the wait
>   timeout. The func is invoked with the last arguments provided to the
>   debounced function. Subsequent calls to the debounced function return
>   the result of the last func invocation.

```
const fn = () => console.log('foo')
const dFn = _.debounce(fn, 500)

dFn()
dFn.cancel()  // Remove this to see it working and leave it to cancel
```

Lets try with `setTimeout`:

```js
const fn = () => setTimeout(function(){console.log('foo')}, 200)
const dFn = _.debounce(fn, 500)

dFn()
dFn.cancel()  // Remove this to see it working and leave it to cancel
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Now if the async function got to the point of being executed there is nothing you can do really.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but will it also cancel the async function? I imagine that the async function will finish, and will not get stopped half way. Imagine abort on an xhr request. Will it work the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My decision is to use **AbortController**. And invoke both `.cancel()` and `.abort()` methods.

[See the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort)